# Calculating the probability of success in k (or less) Bernoulli trials out of n using matlab

Tags: matlab, performance, statistics, probability, binomial-cdf

I am trying to calculate the probability of success in 70 (or less) Bernoulli trials out of 100. I wrote it with Matlab. But, I get the probability to be 1 (it can't be 1 since its not success in all 100 trials).

Is my function OK?

```
syms k
f = nchoosek(100,k)*0.5^k*0.5^(100-k);
F = double(symsum(nchoosek(100,k)*0.5^k*0.5^(100-k),k,0,70));
```

If it is, how can I get a more accurate resault in Matlab?

Thanks

**edit**:
I have have a binary vector that represents success/failure in n trials (like tossing a coin 100 times). And I need the error of my sample (the way statistics does it.. but I don't know statistics). So I thought that maybe i will try to calculate "how far am I from being correct in all trials" which should be 1-F in my code. But then 70 successes out of 100 gives me error = 0 which is obviously not true..

**edit2**: In the example I gave here I need the probability that there are 70 successes in 100 trials.

[image]

Comment: When asking about a mathematical problem, it's pretty fundamental to include the maths you're trying to implement within the question. By not doing so, you've narrowed the pool of potential answerers from "people with MATLAB knowledge" to "people with MATLAB knowledge who have prior understanding of your specific maths problem". Please [edit] the question to explain what you're trying to do, and what your expected results are in terms of a [mcve] - it should be straightforward for you to do a small trial example by hand to verify expected outputs I think

Comment: @Wolfie: OK thanks for the tip. I tried to add it in the *edit* part. I hope its clear enough

Comment: This can be done analytically or empirically. Are you wanting the probability that the first success occurs in the 70th trial?  Or the probability there are 70 successes in 100 trials?  The underlying distribution is different depending on the exact question (Geometric vs. Binomial). Further, if you say "success by 70th trial", it just means using the CDF might be more expedient.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan, I need the probability there are 70 successes in 100 trials

Comment: The **number of successes** in 100 trials is distributed with a [Binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)(*n* = 100, *p* = P(Success)) distribution.  *The probability there are exactly 70 successes in 100 trials* is `binopdf(70,100,0.5)` if `p = 0.5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have everything you need to answer this question.

In the formula you have posted, you sum the probabilities from 0 to 70, that is, it will calculate the probability to have 0 or 1 or 2 .. or 70 successes, which means 70 or less successes.

Without the sum, you get the probability to have exactly `k` successes. The probability to get exactly 70 successes is:

```
k = 70;
f = nchoosek(100,k)*0.5^k*0.5^(100-k)
Warning: Result may not be exact. Coefficient is greater than 9.007199e+15 and is only
accurate to 15 digits 
> In nchoosek (line 92) 

f =

   2.3171e-05
```

You receive a warning that the computation of `nchoosek(100,70)` is not exact (see below for a better way).

To compute the probability to get 70 or less successes, sum over the probabilities to get 0 or 1 or .. 70 successes:

```
>> f = 0;
>> for k=0:70;
f = f + nchoosek(100,k)*.5^k*.5^(100-k);
end
```

You will receive a lot of warnings, but you can look at `f`:

```
>> f

f =

    1.0000
```

As you see, if rounded to four digits, the probability is 1. We know, however, that it must be slighly less than one´. If we ask Matlab to show more digits:

```
>> format long
```

we see that it is not exactly 1:

```
>> f

f =

   0.999983919992352
```

If you compute `1-f`, you will see that the result is not `0` (I switch back to showing less digits):

```
>> format short
>> 1-f

ans =

   1.6080e-05
```

To get rid of the warnings and to simplify the code for computing the probabilities, Matlab provides several functions to deal with binomial distributions. For the probability to get exactly 70 successes, use

```
>> binopdf(70,100,.5)

ans =

   2.3171e-05
```

and to get 70 or less successes:

```
>> format long
>> binocdf(70,100,.5)

ans =

   0.999983919992352
```